# Azure HTTP-triggered Function 404s when deployed

Tags: azure-functions

I have Visual Studio for Mac. I followed [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/mac/azure-functions?view=vsmac-2019) tutorial. I set set the authentication level to "function". I tested it locally and it worked fine. I published it using Visual Studio for Mac and it launched my function and I see a nice blue page. Then I go to the API url and it returns a 404. This is the URL:

> https://idb-dialog-flow.azurewebsites.net/api/idb_dialog_flow?code=(my_code)

I also turned off AlwaysOn mode, though I had this issue before I touched this setting.

Why is it doing this and how can I fix it?

### Edit

Using the Kudo console and PowerShell, I see that my site was deployed, but I only see a function.json file. Isn't there supposed to be more files? Like my .cs function file?

```
PS D:\home\site\wwwroot\idb_dialog_flow> ls
ls


    Directory: D:\home\site\wwwroot\idb_dialog_flow


Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name                          
----                -------------         ------ ----                          
-a----        6/13/2019   4:53 AM            389 function.json                 


PS D:\home\site\wwwroot\idb_dialog_flow>
```

Comment: To debug, use Kudu Console (https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Kudu-console) and see if your function was indeed deployed under d:\home\site\wwwroot.

Comment: You could go to integrate check what HTTP methods you selected.

Comment: And did you just get the url from portal **Get function URL**?

Comment: Please see my updated question. Thank you for the questions you asked. I got the url from `</> Get function URL` button on the azure portal when I open my function there.